# Error trying to make bootable Mavericks USB drive

Tags: macos, usb

[image]

MBP 5,3 running 10.9.4 trying to make a bootable USB 2 drive b/c my wife's HDD on a similar MBP failed. New drive in the mail. I tried using a 4-5 yr old Lexar 8GB and got this vague error.

Since I just bought a new SanDisk 16GB I'm thinking maybe I needed a newer drive, but no go, same error. Have tried to erase, partition, repair, etc both USB drives in Disk Utility.

Answer (score 1):

There is an automation tool called DiskMaker X. All you need for the program to work is the disk image that you are trying to make a usb of. It does all the work for you. Just make sure that you have a full image and not a partial one.

Answer (score 0):

Mavericks needs 8 GB space.

Not sure your Lexar 8GB drive has that space free.

Check for it.

I use following process to make a bootable USB.

Format it, using Disk Utility, as a Mac OS Extended (Journaled) drive, named Mavericks. 
This can be done from the Erase tab within the app; make sure the USB drive **does not** have multiple partitions (that can happen, so turn to the Partition tab to verify and correct this).

Open Terminal and Copy/Paste following.

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Mavericks --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app --no interaction.
```

The process....

Erasing Disk: 0%... 10%... 20%... 30%...100%...

Copying installer files to disk…(this part can take 30 minutes)

Copy complete.

Making disk bootable...

Copying boot files...

Copy complete.

Done.